# Trying to run DROP COLUMN throws a syntax error

Tags: postgresql

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "COLUMN"
>
> LINE 1: DROP COLUMN geom;
> ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 6

Comment: `ALTER TABLE [table_name] DROP COLUMN geom;`... from [the first google result](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/tables/alter_table.php#:~:text=The%20syntax%20to%20drop%20a,of%20the%20table%20to%20modify) when searching for "postresql drop column".

Comment: Show the complete command you ran that got the error as update to answer.  FYI, `DROP COLUMN ...` by itself is not a legitimate command.

Comment: ALTER TABLE pop_place
  DROP COLUMN geom;     returned an error ERROR:  cannot drop column geom of table populated_places because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  view v2 depends on column geom of table populated_places
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
SQL state: 2BP01

Comment: The error is telling you what the problem is, the view `v2` depends on that column. You either need to drop the view first or follow the `HINT` and add `DROP CASCADE`. **Think about this before you do it as it will drop all dependent objects**. At the very least do: `BEGIN; ALTER TABLE pop_table DROP COLUMN ...` so you can `ROLLBACK` if needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.